# installing from USB

Tags: boot

I have done all the steps for making a bootable USB, changed the priority of USB to first, but after rebooting it loads Windows. It doesn't see the USB.

This is using USB 2.0 media. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which software did you use to make your usb bootable?

Comment: Is this a computer with Windows 8 pre-installed?

Comment: On my Asus motherboard, I have two bios settings I need to change, to make it boot from usb: "Boot Device Priority" and "Hard Disk Drives" (-order). Only changing Boot device Priority does not work on this computer. Might be the same in your case.

Comment: Which bootloader do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you made the appropriate settings in your computer's bios then you should try the boot options while booting your computer. Usualy its holding the F12 button. You will be presented with all discoverd boot options. You should see your usb device.